# How do I extract a http link from a text based column in Mysql using sql

Tags: mysql

NOTE: I changed SqlLite to MySQL.

I need to extract html links from a MySQL database text field.

1. The link is not in a fixed position, can be anywhere in the text field.
2. I like the link to be put in a separate column as part of the output.

Example text.
I’m listening to "some nice music". You can listen to it here: https://example.com/?l=sdfsafyNjE
I’m listening to https://example.com/?l=Njksdfa1 with the app.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Use the string functions of whatever language you're using to do stuff with the data from your sql queries.

Comment: Sure that is one way to do it, HOWEVER, I was hoping we could do something with subsctr or something.. I do not know enough about it... it is a scenario of ... "I know the sound but have no idea where it comes from...."

Comment: Sqlite's builtin string handling functions are rather limited. It's easier to move that logic outside of the query itself.

Comment: Hi shawn I change sqllite to mysql...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What should happen if there are multiple URLs within a single text column?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If so, please accept it using the green check mark. If not, please expand on what problems you are continuing to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name, 'https?:\/\/.*?(?=\s)') AS url`

Read more about using regular expressions in the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

You can also do a search for **url regex** to find an expression suitable to your needs. Urls may require more advanced patterns than this example.